# Xdebug in Vagrant laravel/homestead V0.4.0 / v3.0.1

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, xdebug, homestead

I set up a vagrant box laravel/homestead v0.4.0.
I install homestead V3.0.1 using composer. 
Finally I run "vagrant up" and then "vagrant ssh" and i am inside the Homestead VM, but...

It supposed to include `Xdebug`, but it hasn't...
When I run `phpinfo()` there is no Xdebug info.
Also in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` or in the `config.d` folder, there is no configurations for Xdebug.

**My final goal is to be able to debug a laravel project with Netbeans IDE. The project is running inside the homestead VM, but im stuck understanding why there is not Xdebug in the homestead virtual machine.
Any help to achive this is highly appreciated**

Comment: I'm seeing it too. It looks as if XDebug was removed in this latest build. Will follow up with instructions on how to implement.

Comment: taylor added xdebug in [v0.4.1](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.4.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## EDIT: As of version 0.4.1, XDebug was put back into Homestead. Compiling XDebug from source should no longer be necessary.

---

In your `~/.homestead` directory, there should be a file called `after.sh`. This will provide you a means by which you can execute your own commands after the Homestead provisioner has finished.

Copy and paste the following into your `after.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Install Xdebug
git clone git://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git
cd xdebug
phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug
make
make install

# Configure Xdebug
cat > /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini <<EOL
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
EOL
ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Once complete, run a `vagrant destroy` and a `vagrant up`, or run `vagrant provision` to ensure the shell command executes properly.

This version of XDebug is a direct clone of the Github Master branch. **This branch is considered unstable.** Once the Xdebug github account adds a branch for either 2.4 or 2.5, make sure to update your shell command to checkout that branch before running the various configuration and make commands.

Additionally, I'm only adding Xdebug to the FPM configuration. **I am not adding it to the CLI configuration**. You will likely see Xdebug only in a `phpinfo()` call, and not a `php -i` call.

Aside from that, I tested this on my own environment:

- Homestead box version 0.4
- Github clone laravel/homestead 3.0.1
- PHPStorm IDE

Everything seems to work as expected. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I installed manually Xdebug 2.4.0RC3 in the Homestead. After that i folowed this steps to configure netbeans: http://www.papayasoft.com/2013/02/25/debugging-vagrant-virtualbox-vm-netbeans/.Now its working perfect.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered your question, be sure to mark this as answered so that others can see as well.

Answer (score 9):

Just run this in your homestead

```
php -v

sudo phpenmod xdebug

sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need in ~/.homestead/after.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# If you would like to do some extra provisioning you may
# add any commands you wish to this file and they will
# be run after the Homestead machine is provisioned.
apt-get install php-xdebug
```